# SQL Server 2008 increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer, increment

I have one table

```
Table A (ID,RecNo, Old,New)
Table B (ID,AuditDate,Event)
```

How can i make increment on the RecNo become `1,2,3` when my `TableA.ID = TableB.ID`. I am doing audit trigger. For example, if i update 3 fields on the system. 
`TableA.ID` must same as `TableB.ID` and since i update 3 fields,assume the ID is 10, the RecNo will have `1,2,3` and store the old and new value.The ID will auto increment every time event occur. If there is another ID, the RecNo will start from 1 again. I had tried `@recNo = @recNo + 1` but the number keep jumping. Any guideline you all know??

Comment: It's far easier to just assign a globally incrementing value using `IDENTITY` and then `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY GlobalID) as RecNo, ...` when you query the table.

Answer (score 0):

I used [SQL Server Instead Of Trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-instead-of-trigger-with-sequence-table.aspx) for this task,
Here is the sample SQL scripts, I hope they help

I used a temp table in the SQL trigger to get correct results if the insert statement inserts more than one row in one execution

And [SQL Row_Number function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx) is used to prevent if more than one entry is executed for the same id in one statement

You can test the scripts with same INSERT statements given below

```
create table TableA (
        ID int, 
        RecNo int,
        Old int, 
        New int
    )



create Trigger trg_TableAInsert on dbo.TableA Instead Of Insert
 AS
 Begin

    Create Table #temp (id int, MaxRecNo int)
    Insert Into #temp
    Select distinct i.id, MAX(TableA.RecNo) OVER (Partition by i.ID)
    From inserted i
    LEFt JOIN TableA on i.ID = TableA.ID

    Insert Into TableA (ID, RecNo, Old, New)
    Select i.ID, ISNULL(#temp.MaxRecNo,0) + ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by i.id order by i.id), i.Old, i.New
    From inserted i
    inner join #temp on i.ID = #temp.ID

    drop Table #temp

 End



insert into tablea (id, old,new) values (1,1,2)
insert into tablea (id, old,new) values (2,1,2)
insert into tablea (id, old,new) select distinct id,9,10 from TableA
insert into tablea (id, old,new) select top 3 4,0,1 from tablea
select * from tablea
```